# Calling fortran from R via C does not link

Tags: c, r, fortran

I have a routine in fortran, which I wish to use in R via a C implementation. Suppose my fortran file is bivnt.f. Now, `R CMD SHLIB C_Binary.c` and `R CMD SHLIB bivnt.f` do not give any problem but when it comes to linking I obtain

```
> dyn.load("bivnt.so")
> dyn.load("C_Binary.so")
Errore in dyn.load("C_Binary.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/Users/erlisruli/Dropbox/WPapers/ABC-cs/Rcode/CorBinData/C_Binary.so':
  dlopen(/Users/erlisruli/Dropbox/WPapers/ABC-cs/Rcode/CorBinData/C_Binary.so, 6): Symbol not found: _smvbvt_
  Referenced from: /Users/erlisruli/Dropbox/WPapers/ABC-cs/Rcode/CorBinData/C_Binary.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/erlisruli/Dropbox/WPapers/ABC-cs/Rcode/CorBinData/C_Binary.so
```

this seems pretty strange to me, since from nm I obtain

```
$ nm bivnt.so
0000000000003940 s _a.1868
                 U _asin
                 U _atan
                 U _atan2
                 U _exp
0000000000003540 T _mvbvn_
00000000000027a0 T _mvbvt_
0000000000002610 T _mvbvtc_
0000000000002040 T _mvbvtl_
0000000000002d10 T _mvbvu_
0000000000001f20 T _mvphi_
0000000000002b80 T _mvstdt_
                 U _sin
00000000000038a0 T _smvbvt_
0000000000003ba0 s _w.1368
0000000000003aa0 s _x.1369
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Any clue?

P.S. the C_Binary.c is

```
#include<R.h>
/* Calcolo ripartizione normale bivariata */
void F77_SUB(smvbvt)( double* , int* , double*, double* , int* , double* ) ;

void biv_pmnorm( double *prob , int *nu, double *lower , double *upper , int *flag , double *corr )
{ 
  F77_CALL(smvbvt)( prob , nu , lower , upper , flag , corr ) ;
} 
//pairwise log-likelihood-->output: units
void bin_pairwise_llik( double *res , double *data , double *cov, double *theta , int *n , int *nc  ) /* n = #righe ; nc = #colonne*/
{
    register int k, i, j, ite=0;
    int nu=0, flag[2];
    double res2=0.0 , res3=0.0, corr=theta[2], lower[2], upper[2];

    for( k=0; k<*n; k++ )
    {
        for( i=0; i<(*nc-1); i++ )
        {
            for( j=(i+1); j<*nc; j++ )
            {
                 if(*(data + i + k**nc)==1) 
                 {
                     lower[0] = -*(theta+0)-*(theta+1)**(cov + i + k**nc);
                     upper[0] = 0.0;
                     flag[0]  = 1;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     lower[0] = 0.0;
                     upper[0] = -*(theta+0)-*(theta+1)**(cov + i + k**nc);
                     flag[0]  = 0;

                 }

                 if(*(data + j + k**nc)==1)
                 {
                     lower[1] = -*(theta+0)-*(theta+1)**(cov + j + k**nc);
                     upper[1] = 0.0;
                     flag[1]  = 1;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     lower[1] = 0.0;
                     upper[1] = -*(theta+0)-*(theta+1)**(cov + j + k**nc);
                     flag[1]  = 0;
                 }

                 biv_pmnorm( &res2, &nu, lower, upper, flag, &corr ) ;
                 res3+=log(res2);
                 ite += 1;
            } 
        }
         res[k]=res3;
         res3=0.0; 
    }
}


//pairwise log-likelihood-->output: one value
void bin_pairwise_llik_sum( double *res , double *data , double *cov, double *theta , int *n , int *nc  ) /* n = #righe ; nc = #colonne*/
{
    register int k, i, j, ite=0;
    int nu=0, flag[2];
    double res2=0.0 , corr=theta[2], lower[2], upper[2];
    *res=0.0;

    for( k=0; k<*n; k++ )
    {
        for( i=0; i<(*nc-1); i++ )
        {
            for( j=(i+1); j<*nc; j++ )
            {
                 if(*(data + i + k**nc)==1) 
                 {
                     lower[0] = -*(theta+0)-*(theta+1)**(cov + i + k**nc);
                     upper[0] = 0.0;
                     flag[0]  = 1;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     lower[0] = 0.0;
                     upper[0] = -*(theta+0)-*(theta+1)**(cov + i + k**nc);
                     flag[0]  = 0;

                 }

                 if(*(data + j + k**nc)==1)
                 {
                     lower[1] = -*(theta+0)-*(theta+1)**(cov + j + k**nc);
                     upper[1] = 0.0;
                     flag[1]  = 1;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     lower[1] = 0.0;
                     upper[1] = -*(theta+0)-*(theta+1)**(cov + j + k**nc);
                     flag[1]  = 0;
                 }

                 biv_pmnorm( &res2, &nu, lower, upper, flag, &corr ) ;
                 *res+=log(res2); 

                 ite += 1;
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```